# Direct access to C++ ATL COM objects

Tags: c++, dll, com, atl

I have an ATL/COM implementation of an interface, which I need to instantiate in my main code and pass to another COM object. This implementation is in C++.

From my main C++ code, I would like to access directly to the object (not through the COM port), and access class members and methods directly.

I think that the way to go is to add `DECLARE_NO_REGISTRY()` in the ATL/COM class; then call `myCOMClass:CreateObject()` instead of `CoCreateInstance`; but I do not know how to use this (and did not find any example).

I tried several combinations with no success.

In my main code:

```
//I added this line to call the lib directly
#include "comClass\StdAfx.h"
#include "comClass\comClass_i.c"
#include "comClass\comClass.h"

//I removed this line to bypass COM
//#import  "comClass\comClass.dll"

//What can I put here to replace this block, bypass COM
//and being able to access class members??
CoInitialize(NULL);
comClassInterface *myObject = NULL;
HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(comClass),
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    __uuidof(comClassInterface),
    (void**)&myObject);
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Creating a simple ATL COM class in Visual Studio produces something which is far from a minimal example. Maybe the question is not clear enough, but I try to find the method to do what I need rather than fixing a code.

Comment: You definitely need to show some relevant code.

Comment: I added some code, hoping it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

More or less "standard" wat to create COM objects directly:

```
CComObject<comClass> *myObject;
CComObject<comClass>::CreateInstance(&myObject);
```

That's it basically.. You could also just do "new comClass" if the class is not abstract, which is normally the case when you use ATL.